# if SELECT HOUR(CURTIME()) BETWEEN 0 AND 10

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a select only if the time is between 0 and 10.
If statement is true => select1 else => select2. 
So I thought it should be something like this:

```
if (SELECT HOUR(CURTIME()) BETWEEN 0 AND 10)
then 
SELECT `s` FROM `svs` WHERE `a`=1 OR `a`=2         //select1
else
SELECT `s` FROM `svs` WHERE `a`=1        //select2
```

But I don't know what am I missing( what am I doing wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if`/`then`/`else` syntax does not exist in SQL. Conditional expressions do exist, but they let you produce a single column, not a collection of rows.

Since the two queries that you run are almost identical, you can solve your problem with a single query:

```
SELECT `s` FROM `svs` WHERE `a`=1 OR (`a`=2 AND HOUR(CURTIME()) BETWEEN 0 AND 10)
```

This adds rows where `a=2` only between the hours of 0 and 10, inclusive.